# How do I change the appearance of the address bar and tab in Chromium to be similar to the attached image

Tags: javascript, python, c++, c, chromium

[The top image is compiled Chromium and the bottom one is a design I made in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD88T.png)

I downloaded the gclient files and can now see all the components that make the Chrome build. The files are a lot though and I didn't find the file responsible for this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/views/location_bar/location_bar_view.cc;l=1

most of the ui stuff you would want to customize is in chrome/browser/ui/views

and most of the ui graphics are in
ui/resources/default_100_percent/

200_percent is for the retina displays, basically 2x resolution